# Your account already has a signing certificate for this machine but it is not present in your keychain

Tags: xcode8, ios10

I get this error, verbatim, when trying to build and install to a device.

This is my environment:

- Xcode 8
- El Capitan

Has anyone run into this problem? How did you solve it?

Thank you

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: I have this error, I see a 'revoke' button ... isn't this going to revoke my whole team's signing cert?

Comment: One time I tried revoking the certificate, XCode didn't even tell me about the consequence of what could happen and I ended up revoking the certificate of all our enterprise app users.  We had to recreate the certificate, recompile and redeploy... terrible.

Answer (score 81):

Go to Xcode `Preferences` -> `Accounts` tab -> Double-click your team name -> Click the `+` at the bottom left of the dialog box that appears -> Select `iOS Development`.

This will create a new development certificate that will allow you to install and test on your device.

Comment: works for me, it seems like you need a pair of certificate when you use automatically manage signing?

Comment: After adding the new certificate, I still needed to revoke the old one (by selecting revoke from the dialog after attempting a build).

Comment: This worked but I needed to close Xcode and reopen after doing what the answer says. Then when running it asked me for the password to access my Keychain. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. I was signed in with a different user profile on my Mac. I selected 'Apple Development', since 'iOS Development' isn't present now these days.

Answer (score 6):

In my case problem was in revoked certificate.
To fix this problem:

1. Go to `Xcode` –> `Preferences` –> `Accounts` –> Select needed `Apple ID` –> Double-click your `Team` –> Check certificate with `Status` `Revoked`.
2. Go to `Keychain Access` –> `Search` for certificate was revoked –> `Delete` it.

Comment: after you run the above steps, you shut down Xcode and reopen and clean/build and run. Worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I got this error immediately after a repair to replace the MagSafe module on my MacBook Pro (I am guessing the long period with the battery unplugged reset the SMC). I really didn't want to recreate the signing certificate so I went into the Keychain, realised I had so many expired keys still present and decided to delete the expired ones. I Go back to Xcode, clean the project and rebuild and boom...everything works fine. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

go to your apple developer site and download the signing certificate.  Once downloaded you should be able to click and it will auto do its thing and should be good after that

Comment: this didn't work for me. I had to revoke my old one and create a new certificate

Comment: @rakappdev how did you create a new certificate ?

Comment: revoke your old certificate first. Then create a new one (google it).

Comment: Isn't this going to revoke and recreate my team's distribution cert, as in my 'Team' I see my companies team name.  Anyone know the right way to manage this stuff?  what a mess...