# Xcode: "Revoke certificate - Your account already has a signing certificate for this machine but it is not present in your keychain."

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm posting this as a question and providing the answer for the benefit of others running into the same situation and searching for the solution as this had me scratching my head and wasting time and searching past questions until I eventually discovered the cause.

I got this error but nothing about my project; my accounts; my certificates; my mac set up had changed. In particular the certificates are still valid and have not been revoked.

> Revoke certificate Your account already has a signing certificate for
>   this machine but it is not present in your keychain. To create a new
>   one, you must first revoke the existing certificate.

With no obvious cause for the problem suddenly appearing, I eventually discovered the cause, posted as the answer below.

Comment: **This Answer work for me :** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424878/your-account-already-has-a-signing-certificate-for-this-machine-but-it-is-not-pr/44170235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the problem was that the certificate was installed on the user `A`, but when I logged with the user `B` I got this error. What I did was on the user `A` I opened the `Keychain Access.app`, looked for the certificate that I needed (under My certificates on the left side), exported it and then on the user `B`, add the certificate.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion the answer provided by ykay in this post [Your account already has a signing certificate for this machine but it is not present in your keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424878/your-account-already-has-a-signing-certificate-for-this-machine-but-it-is-not-pr/44170235) should be the correct answer to this issue - it is quick and painless and does NOT involve REVOKING any certificates

Comment: Agreed - this is a lot easier than described above

Comment: Yes, highly recommended!

Answer (score 10):

This is what worked for me...

It seemed I was missing some certificates in Keychain Access. I had to install the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority. See the two articles below:

(Installing Missing Intermediate Certificate Authorities)
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW30

https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/

Comment: Lifesaver! You can verify if this is your problem by opening Keychain access > search your developer certificate > select the certificate. If it has a red warning indicating "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority" then this is your problem. Copy the "issued by" name (which is below the selected certificate name) and download and install that certificate. You certificate should turn green then :-)

Answer (score 5):

I have found Many answer:

**But This Answer help for me:**

Go to Xcode Preferences -> Accounts tab -> Double-click your team name -> Click the + at the bottom left of the dialog box that appears -> Select iOS Development.

[Your account already has a signing certificate for this machine but it is not present in your keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424878/your-account-already-has-a-signing-certificate-for-this-machine-but-it-is-not-pr/44170235)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a bug with XCode 8.3 beta 4 (also present in Xcode 8.3 beta 3) and will occur if your device is not registered on your Apple account.

Xcode is displaying the wrong error message, if the same device/project is opened with Xcode 8.2, then the correct message is displayed:

[image]

Instead of displaying this message, Xcode is erroneously reporting the message about needing to revoke the certificate.

[image]

Obviously the solution is to register the device, which must be done manually as 8.3 is no longer recognizing that situation and offering it as an option.
Or open the project in Xcode 8.2 and register the device via Xcode and then re-open the project in Xcode 8.3

Comment: This will not work since my device is "Generic iOS Device". However, cormacnchees' answere worked perfectly, adding the "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority"

Comment: My device was already registered with the Developer program and I was using it until I upgraded it to iOS 15 beta. Do you think thats what's causing the issue? I am still using Xcode 11.3 btw because to upgrade requires a lot of time. I already copied the device support files for iOS 15 into my Xcode

Answer (score 0):

You can tap on 'Manage Certificates' and after add new 'Apple Development' certificate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when the subscription expired and I had to reissue the certificates.

I was able to get rid of the error by deleting the old provisioning profiles from: ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles

Answer (score -1):

May be one of certificates included in your provisioning is revoked.
Did you try enter "https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate" then edit your provisioning by add again your certificate which revoked already?

Comment: As was mentioned in the question - nothing about the certificates had changed, this includes being revoked. However did you actually read the fact the question states "I'm posting this as a question and providing the answer" and "I eventually discovered the cause, posted as the answer below."