# Test has one Apple distribution certificate but its private key is not installed

Tags: ios, swift

After a lot of work, I finally was able to get my ios app archived, but now when I archive the IOS app I get the following error:

```
Test has one Apple distribution certificate but its private key is not installed
```

What should I do?

I did the following:

1. Request a certificate from certificate authority
2. Uploaded that certificate in https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list

Comment: When you first ran an archive build using your developer account, did you do it on another Mac?  This happened to me when I originally let XCode create the certificate on another computer, so I had to grab the exported private keys from that computer, and import them into the MacBook I was using to archive and submit the app to the App Store.

Comment: @SuperTully Is there a way to revoke and start over?

Comment: Yes, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424878/your-account-already-has-a-signing-certificate-for-this-machine-but-it-is-not-pr/44170235), it gives an example of how to deal with this issue.  It's just a certificate used for distributing apps to the App Store, so if you're the only one using it, you shouldn't have a problem revoking the cert and just issuing a new one.  If other users use it, then you could create a headache.

Comment: @SuperTully I tried all of your suggestions, but unfortunately, I'm still getting the error.